# lim sup of nonoverlapping subintervals

Tags: elementary-set-theory, limsup-and-liminf

On the interval $A = (0, 1]$, define the subintervals $A_0 = (0, \frac{1}{2}]$, $A_1 = (\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{4}]$, $A_2 = (\frac{3}{4}, \frac{7}{8}]$, $\ldots$, $A_n= (\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}, \frac{2^{n+1}-1}{2^{n+1}}]$, $\ldots$.

Am I right to say that $\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} A_n = \{1\}$? And if so, how should I reconcile this with the usual interpretation of lim sup that "$\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}A_n$ is the set of outcomes that occur infinitely many times within the infinite sequence of events $A_n$", since $\{1\}$ only occurs once?

Comment: Looks to me like $1$ occurs not once, but _zero_ times. Why would it be in the limsup?

Comment: I tried the direct definition: lim sup$A_n = \cap_{n\ge1} \cup_{m\ge n}A_m$ which comes down to $(0, 1]\cap (1/2, 1] \cap (3/4, 1]\cap \ldots$. It seems to me since ${1}$ is in all of these intersected sets, it should be the limit.

Comment: Why would $1$ be in _any_ of the $\bigcup_{m\ge n}A_m$? It is not in any of the $A_m$, so how would it suddenly turn up in their union?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I see it now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are wrong. Since $\limsup_nA_n$ is the set of all elements of $A$ that belong to infinitely many $A_n$'s, $\limsup_nA_n=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 2):

Let's define the limsup of a sequence of sets as follows:

$$\limsup A_n =\bigcap_{n \geq 1}\bigcup_{k \geq n} A_k$$
Using this definition which is the natural generalization of the limsup of a sequence of numbers, you should be able to show that $\limsup A_n = \emptyset$.

Comment: Then I guess my mistake is in assuming that lim sup$A_n = \cap_{n\ge1} \cup_{m\ge n}A_m$ = $(0, 1]\cap (1/2, 1] \cap (3/4, 1]\cap \ldots$, while the correct answer is  lim sup$A_n = (0, 1)\cap (1/2, 1) \cap (3/4, 1)\cap \ldots$?

Comment: @Javad  Yes, you're right. $1$ is not in any of the $A_m$'s but I think you thought it was and hence the mistake.